# Concurrent uploads in SFTP

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I'm trying to establish an ubuntu server designed to allow SFTP. The SFTP works, however I want to make sure that files don't upload concurrently. For example, if i was uploading

```
first.file
second.file
finish.file
```

it's important that the server receives these in the order that they're uploading, if the server receives the finish file before one of the others ( because it's a significantly smaller file) then that'll cause an issue.

I don't know if this is already how SFTP works, and that as long as you upload in that order, that they'll work this way or if I need to configure the server someway to not allow concurrent uploads.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: If the order of first and second don't matter, can't you just issue 2 separate FTP commands .. the first for the actual data files and the second for the finish file?

Comment: I could! but I'm not the one sending the files, I'm just trying to foolproof it.

Comment: If you can't control it, you can't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFTP doesn't care at all about this. Either change your system on the server side so it doesn't create an issue or on the client side so this problem is taken into account and the files are uploaded one after the other.